# Sybase SQL: How to check if date or timestamp field is empty

Tags: sql, sybase

How to check in Sybase if a date or timestamp field is empty? Unfortunately "is NULL" doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a solution to this problem:

```
select * from ... where ... and CAST(myDateFieldName as CHAR) is NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Visual FoxPro 8.1 ODBC to SYBASE v11.1, use the following query

```
UPDATE table SET thedatefield = CURDATE() WHERE thedatefield IS NULL or EMPTY(thedatefield)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [datalength](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks135.htm) to check that whether field is `empty` or not. You can check in following way:

```
select column_name
from your_table
where datalength(checking_col_name) = 0
```